# Mensaje "No se puede ejecutar esta aplicación en el equipo" al tratar de ejecutar un .bat

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Trato de ejecutar un archivo .bat desde la app "Ejecutar" de windows 10, el .bat hace correr un script escrito en python y al momento de darle aceptar me sale el mensaje "No se puede ejecutar esta aplicación en el equipo" le doy aceptar y no lo ejecuta, ya agregué el directorio del script a las variables del entorno PATH, el bat si se ejecuta si le doy click derecho y lo ejecuto como admin.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo del bat es

```
@py.exe "ruta absoluta del archivo .py %*"
```

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso lo hago asi:

```
@echo off

cd c:\*ruta del directorio del archivo .py*
python archivo.py
exit
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta puede ser apropiada, es recomendable que cuando se de la misma contenga una explicación del porque es válida, para la pregunta de quien la hace, y no vale solo con pegar un código, para que no se reporte como de baja calidad. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].